# How to wait to execute the process before the second form close in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

There is a method when clicking button.

After clicking the button, I navigate to the second Page just to show the information to users.

I want to continue the coding after the second Page disappear (when the user click the OK Button). You can follow below photo and coding.

I used await method but it continues to the below coding as I do not want to.

Should I use await method to use or is there anything that I can use Navigation.PushAsync better than this?

Please help.

```
private async Task InitDownload()
{
  bool isInboundExist = false; 
  if (isInboundExist)
 {
  //Show information to user which is new form with button Ok
  await Navigation.PushAsync(new FrmInProgress());
  
  //Do the process
  InRec();
 
  //Show information to user it is complete, which is new form with Button Ok.
  await Navigation.PushAsync(new FrmComplete());

  //Reach to the main page after everything is done
  await Navigation.PushAsync(new MainVerifyPage());
 }

}
```

What I want to do is show **FrmInProgess** Page first, click Ok, reach to previous Page and do process. After that shows **FrmComplete** Page, click Ok to back. Finally reach to **Main Page**.

What is happening now is reach to **Main Page** first. When I click back button, it reached to **FrmComplete** Page. And when I click OK button from **FrmComplete page**, it reached to FrmInProgress Page.

frmInProgess Page

[image: FrmInPorgress page]

FrmComplete Page

[image]

Comment: How about using the `Popup` to display the `FrmInProgess` and `FrmComplete` pages? You do not need to use three Navigation.PushAsync methods.  Here is the sample for you to refer to [Xamarin Community Toolkit Popup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/community-toolkit/views/popup).

Comment: *" want to continue the coding after the second Page disappear"*. Don't try to do that in the same method. Instead, have second page send a [Message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/maui/communicating-between-components) in its `OnDisappearing`. Have first page register to receive that message, and execute desired code.